# Simple Injector is missing one of the open generic types after it is registered - what might be happening?

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm having some difficulty with registering some open generic types with simple injector.

In startup I am registering in the following way..

```
 var assemblies = LoadAssemblies("MyProjectName");
 _container.Register(typeof(IMessageProcessor<>), assemblies, Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

When I try to get an instance one of them is missing. If I try to explicitly register the instance I get an error that it is already registered so i'm a bit lost as to what is happening.

I have checked the classes and they all look the same and exist in the same assembly.

The interfaces look like...

```
public interface IBaseMessageProcessor
{
    Task Process<T>(T message);
}

public interface IMessageProcessor<T> : IBaseMessageProcessor where T : BaseMessage
{
    Task Process(T message);
}
```

There are multiple examples that implement these interfaces that look like..

```
public interface IAssignToMultipleMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor<AssignToMultipleMessage> { }

public interface IReturnBenefitMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor<ReturnBenefitMessage> { } 

public interface IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor<AssignWelcomeBenefitsMessage> { }
```

In total there are six like `IMessageProcessor<>` where the Messages all inherit from `BaseMessage`

The concerete example of the above three look like this..

```
public class AssignToMultipleMessageProcessor : IAssignToMultipleMessageProcessor
{
    public async Task Process(AssignToMultipleMessage message)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task Process<T>(T message)
    {
        if (message is AssignToMultipleMessage assignToMultipleMessage)
        {
            await Process(assignToMultipleMessage);
        }
    }
}

public class ReturnBenefitMessageProcessor : IReturnBenefitMessageProcessor
{
    public async Task Process(ReturnBenefitMessage message)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task Process<T>(T message)
    {
        if (message is ReturnBenefitMessage assignToMultipleMessage)
        {
            await Process(assignToMultipleMessage);
        }
    }
}

public class AssignWelcomeBenefitMessageProcessor : IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor
{
    public async Task Process(AssignWelcomeBenefitsMessage message)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task Process<T>(T message)
    {
        if (message is AssignWelcomeBenefitsMessage assignWelcomeBenefitsMessage)
        {
            await Process(assignWelcomeBenefitsMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the startup the container shows all six instances are in the `LifeStyleRegistrationCache` of the container as Singletons.

Later when trying to get the instance...

```
var instance = scope.GetInstance<IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor>();
```

All six are still present in the `LifeStyleResistrationCache` as Singletons  but the error is thrown

`No registration for type IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor could be found.`

In the `LifeStyleRegistrationCache` it shows `{[{Name = AssignWelcomeBenefitMessageProcessor FullName = MyAppName.MessageProcessing.AssignWelcomeBenefitMessageProcessor}, {System.WeakReference}]}`

The SerializationStackTraceString says...

`at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException(Type type)\r\n   at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceFromProducer(InstanceProducer instanceProducer, Type serviceType)\r\n   at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType(Type serviceType)\r\n   at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type serviceType)\r\n   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)\r\n   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TService]()\r\n`

All the other five instances can be successfully resolved in the same way but this one is failing. Would really appreciate some help on this if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Cheers :)

Comment: Have you registered any `IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor` instance in your container?

Comment: I believe so yes - the first code snippet in my post is how all instances that implement `IMessageProcessor<>` are being registered with `IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor` being one of six that does. If i call `var instance = scope.GetInstance<IReturnBenefitsMessageProcessor>();` it works. Only the `IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor` is failing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others which shows that getting a `IReturnBenefitsMessageProcessor` instance is working, but `IAssignWelcomeBenefitsMessageProcessor` is not.

Comment: A call to `_container.Register(typeof(IMessageProcessor<>)` does *only* register supplied implementations for their defined `IMessageProcessor<T>` interface. It will *not* automatically add registrations for other interfaces that those types might implement, even if those interfaces are subtypes of `IMessageProcessor<T>`. You will have to make those registrations *explicitly*. This is the most likely cause of your problem.

Comment: @Steven, thank you - but then why is it seemingly registering all the other instances that are subtypes in the same way? I just tried to register each explicitly and that worked :) I am confused as to why it manages to register the other five examples and not this one. Thanks again!

Comment: I can't answer your question. For that, I need to see an MRE, as @Progman also mentioned.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to do that - might take me some time as this is in a production app so I will need to recreate the critical parts in a seperate project ;) Thanks @Steven and Progman for the help

Comment: Arghgh! I found out what was going on - there was a sneaky extension method that was registering all instances by default naming conventions and of course my troubled instance had an extra `s` in the name - doh! Knew it had to be something like that. Thanks again to you both, I will crawl back to the shadows in shame.